# Java server side validation for HTML and other invalid inputs

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How can I prevent user from entering HTML or Java script tags in input type in Spring MVC? There should be a server side validation. I am working on a project with thousands of JSPs and controllers. How can I do this?

Comment: You can always do the ol' `.replace("<", "&gt;")`. I'm sure there's also some libraries out there with wonderful examples of html escaping

Comment: You need to check that on browser in javascript code

Comment: Our client want it to be handled at server side also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a server side solution, you could implement a redirect filter that eliminates everything that contains javascript tags and javascript code. Another way is to check the input values in the controller's method that is associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to redesign a few things. First, you should always validate the user input twice: once client-side, once server-side.

Thus, you will need to validate the user input in your JavaScript code (using a Regexp probably), and to validate it again in your Java code.

If your application follow the usual design patterns, your controller receives a DTO as a parameter to the entry-point. There you can use the `@Valid` annotation and add all the necessary rules on the fields of your DTO (using `javax.validation` annotations).

Answer (score 0):

While there may be many possible answers, one of them is using JSR 303 validator framework.

You can include [hibernate validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/) to use JSR 303 framework.

First step is applying different type of constraint on your class. For example

*example taken from : [Hibernate Validator - Reference - 1.2. Applying constraints](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted-createmodel)*

```
package org.hibernate.validator.referenceguide.chapter01;

import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Car {

    @NotNull //manufacturer must never be null
    private String manufacturer;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 14) //licensePlate must never be null and must be between 2 and 14 characters long
    private String licensePlate;

    @Min(2) 
    private int seatCount; //seatCount must be at least 2

    //getters and setters ...
}
```

Now in your controller, use `@Valid` annotation to validate your car object and also pass a `BindingResult` parameter, that will validate whether this object is valid or not

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/car")
public class CarController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newcar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addCustomer(@Valid Car car, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            //car data is not valid, enter data again
            return "AddNewCar.jsp";
        } else {
            //save car logic here
            return "CarSavedSuccessfully.jsp";
        }
    }
}
```